# Express and Mongoose with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hy guys, i have a this cose for the created the list:

#### Document User Json Example

```
{
    "__v" : 3,
    "_id" : ObjectId("5396e11c13e345570ae174f1"),
    "created" : ISODate("2014-06-10T10:42:36.925Z"),
    "name" : "Project",
    "projects" : [ 
        ObjectId("5396db4f3458c64f09e23ef8"), 
        ObjectId("53982440de337a4e0b3013a4")
    ]
}
```

#### Model User

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
    name    : String,
    projects: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'Project'
    },
    created : Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

#### Model Project

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var Project = new Schema({
    name    : String,
    key     : String,
    description : String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', Project);
```

#### Route/Index.js

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    User.find(function (err, result) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'List',
            user: result
        });
    }).populate('projects');
};
```

#### Index.ejs

```
//foreach
<%= user.projects.name %>
```

but I get undefined, Why? I would like the name of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `populate` on your `find` query *before* you start executing it:

```
User.find().populate('projects').exec(function (err, result) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'List',
        user: result
    });
});
```